# Scaling Matrix?

Tags: matrices, vectors, transformation

I have two matrix problems which I have no idea of how to start solving. If possible could someone guide me through this?
Links to videos would be great so I can solve future problems myself

1) Find the scaling matrix that scales 3 units on the x-axis, -1 unit on the y-axis and 2 units on the z-axis. Thus use this matrix to scale the vertex [1, 1, 1, 1]^(T)

2) Find the scaling matrix that scales 6 units on the x-axis, 5 unit on the y-axis and -3 units on the z-axis. Thus use this matrix to scale the vertex [1, 1, 1, 1]^(T)

**Edit**

Do i use a scaling matrix but change the values of that scaling matrix to the specified values in the question ?
So if i were to do this for the first question i would have to change the scaling matrix accordingly.
But i don't know what to do for the last sentence of the question.

Wait actually do i form a row/column matrix to multiplies with the scaling matrix and then i make a transpose of that. That is switch the rows with columns and vice versa.

Comment: Before someone answers this, what have you tried? And, where are you stuck? I know you said you are not sure where to get started, but this question isn't so bad

Comment: The vertex seems to have one coordinate too many. But to find the matrices you can first find the images of the vectors in the standard basis; then the matrix will have those as its columns.